# the solution of this equation comes in terms of Roots and i don't know how can i simplify this solution please help me

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear

```
Solve[(u (Sqrt[8 p] - 3 Sqrt[u])^2 (Sqrt[8 p] Sqrt[u] - 2 p - 3 u))/(
   2 (Sqrt[u] - Sqrt[8 p])^2) + (2 p)/3 == 0, u]
```

Comment: Why do you think that there is a closed-form solution?

Comment: That's not my point, My only concern about the solution of this equation is in the free form of Roots.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is pick a value for `p` and the `Root` goes away.

```
sol = Solve[(u (Sqrt[8 p] - 3 Sqrt[u])^2 (Sqrt[8 p] Sqrt[u] - 2 p - 3 u))/(2 (Sqrt[u] - Sqrt[8 p])^2) + (2 p)/3 == 0, u]

sol /. p -> .1

{{u -> 0.0842808}, {u -> 
   0.217977}, {u -> -0.144139 - 0.00221632 I}, {u -> -0.144139 + 
    0.00221632 I}, {u -> 0.0596765 - 0.193184 I}, {u -> 
   0.0596765 + 0.193184 I}}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bill watts, but whenever I pick p=100 then root still there.

Comment: Try 100. Instead of an integer, or add //N.

Comment: @Qutubu - With an **exact** input (100), you get an **exact** result (the Root expression). As @BillWatts indicated, to get an approximate result use an **inexact** input or use `N` to convert the **exact** solution (Root) to its approximate value.